# Facebook FQL Subquery

Tags: iphone, sql, facebook-fql

Im using the below query to fetch all the events that I have accepted the invitation to:

```
NSString *eventQuery = @"SELECT eid, name, creator FROM event WHERE eid IN 
( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND rsvp_status='attending' )";
```

This works perfectly, but now I want to get the name of the creator too. Since the creator field is just the userid of the creator I have to do another subquery.

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to issue an FQL multiquery to get this. I'm not sure of how you do this in Objective C, but the FQL syntax is:

```
{ 
   "user_events":
      "SELECT eid, name, creator FROM event WHERE eid IN 
        (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=me() and rsvp_status='attending')",
   "event_creators":
       "SELECT name, id FROM profile WHERE id IN 
         (SELECT creator FROM #user_events)"   
 }
```

Your original problem with no "maybe" events getting returned is because `rsvp_status='maybe'` is incorrect. `rsvp_status='unsure'` is the correct syntax.

Comment: I actually corrected maybe to unsure and removed that part of the Q before you answered, but thanks anyways. I was hoping that I wouldnt have to use multiquery for this. Are you sure that this cant be done using subquery?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. FQL doesn't have a `JOIN`. If you need to get data from two tables, you need to use two queries.

Comment: Okey, just give me a sec to sort out the correct syntax for objective-c and I will approve your answer.

Comment: I had to change the query and syntax abit, but it works perfectly now. Thanks!